# How to connect Parse to Android Studio app?

Tags: android, objective-c, android-studio, parse-platform, sdk

I have tried implementing the dependencies to my app, but the app fails to run once I do so. Additionally, I have gone online and have found sources that tell me to download different projects to use as a foundation or different dependencies to add. Some clarification would be appreciated

Comment: Parse is no more my friend

Comment: @akshay_shahane it returned my friend

Comment: that's good new then

Answer (score 1):

add this to your dependencies:

```
compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.16.0'
```

add this inside your `<application>` in the manifest:

```
 <application ...>
  <meta-data
    android:name="com.parse.SERVER_URL"
    android:value="@string/parse_server_url" />
  <meta-data
    android:name="com.parse.APPLICATION_ID"
    android:value="@string/parse_app_id" />
  ...
</application>
```

or initialize in your activity:

```
   import com.parse.Parse;
import android.app.Application;

public class App extends Application {
  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Parse.initialize(new Parse.Configuration.Builder(this)
      .applicationId("YOUR_APP_ID")
      .server("http://localhost:1337/parse/")
      .build()
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, unfortunately, I tried this and got "Failed to resolve: com...support-annotations:26.0.1" as the result (which is what the previous results were too). Is there anything else I should add?

Comment: what is your build tools?